# How can I calculate the volume of spatial geometry?

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, computational-geometry

In the square prism ABCD A1B1C1D1, AB=2, A1B1=1, AA1=Sqrt [2], what is the volume of this prism?

It is easy to calculate its volume using the volume formula:

```
In[489]:= v = 1/3 (4 + 1 + 2) Sqrt[3/2]

Out[489]= 7/Sqrt[6]
```

Is there another method to calculate the volume of the regular quadrilateral prism based on the known conditions in the software and the graph? That is to say, for any drawn spatial geometry, what method is there to calculate their volume?

Draw the graph of the pyramid according to the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {Sqrt[2], 0, 0};
b = {0, Sqrt[2], 0};
c = -a;
d = -b;
o = Mean[{a, b, c, d}]
h = Sqrt[6]/2;
a1 = {Sqrt[2]/2, 0, h};
b1 = {0, Sqrt[2]/2, h};
c1 = {-Sqrt[2]/2, 0, h};
d1 = {0, -Sqrt[2]/2, h};
o1 = Mean[{a1, b1, c1, d1}]
labels = {Text[Style[O, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o, {-1, -1}],
   Text[Style[O1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o1, {-1, -1}],
   Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {-1, -1}],
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}],
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {1, 1}],
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {-2, 0}],
   Text[Style[A1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a1, {3, 0}],
   Text[Style[B1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b1, {-1, -2}],
   Text[Style[C1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c1, {0, 1}],
   Text[Style[D1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d1, {3, 0}]};
dashLines = {Dashed,
   AbsoluteThickness[2], {Line[{{o, o1}, {d, d1}}]}, {Red,
    Line[{{c, d}, {a, d}, {b, d}, {a, c}}]}};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2],
   Line[{{a, b}, {b, b1}, {a1, a}, {b, b1}, {b1, a1}, {c, c1}, {b1,
      c1}, {c1, d1}, {b, c}, {a1, c1}, {b1, d1}, {a1, d1}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False,
  ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}],
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{o1 - o, o1 - o + {0, 0, 1}}, {a - o,
      a - o + {1, 0, 0}}, {b - o, b - o + {0, 1, 0}}}],
   Text[Style["z", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"],
    o1 - o + {0, 0, 1}, {-1, -1}],
   Text[Style["y", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"],
    b - o + {0, 1, 0}, {-2, -1}],
   Text[Style["x", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"],
    a - o + {1, 0, 0}, {2, -1}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You could use polygons instead of lines, to make the faces of the pyramid, convert to a region with DiscretizeGraphics and then get the volume of the region.

Comment: Related:  [How to optimize the method of drawing a square pyramidal frustum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286392/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the regions you're interested in are convex (e.g., no holes), as in the case of this pyramid, you can create a region from the points, and then get its volume

```
Volume[ ConvexHullRegion[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}] ]
```

which gives `7/Sqrt[6]`.

Answer (score 6):

You want [`Hexahedron`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hexahedron.html), which specifies a geometric region with six quadrilateral sides via a list of vertices.  Note that the vertices need to be ordered in a specific way, described in the documentation;  in your case, though, it's just the "obvious" ordering.  Note also that you can run into [weird behavior if your vertices are not coplanar;](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286270/) `Hexahedron` does not check for this, apparently.

```
reg = Hexahedron[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}]
Volume[reg]
Graphics3D[reg]

(* 7/Sqrt[6] *)
```

[image]

You can further use built-in Mathematica functions to calculate things like centroids, nearest points, etc.  Examples of this can be found in the above-linked documentation page.

Answer (score 6):

Since the prism under consideration is a convex set, one may produce

```
Volume[ConvexHullRegion[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}]]
```

> `7/Sqrt[6]`

```
Region[ConvexHullRegion[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can generalize a solution using a function to define a square pyramidal frustum that's base-centered at the origin. The `squareFrustum` function computes coordinate points for `Hexahedron` from the prism's base and top widths, and its height. The advantage is that `squareFrustum` replaces the need to make manual assignments for the coordinates *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, etc.

```
squareFrustum[wb_,wt_,h_] := With[{p1={-wb/2,-wb/2,0}, p5={-wt/2,-wt/2,h}},
  Hexahedron[{p1, p1+{wb,0,0}, p1+{wb,wb,0}, p1+{0,wb,0},
    p5, p5+{wt,0,0}, p5+{wt,wt,0}, p5+{0,wt,0}}]]
```

We're given the slant length, but we need height so let's calculate it where *b1* is the width of the base (AB=2), *b2* is the width of the top (A1B1=1), and *c* is the slant length (AA1=$\sqrt{2}$).

```
height = Sqrt[c^2 - 1/2*(b1 - b2)^2] /. {b1->2, b2->1, c->Sqrt[2]};
```

Next, define a symbolic definition for the prism, where the base width is *b1*, the top width is *b2*, and height is *h*. Then, `Volume` gives the formula for volume, and substituting numeric values gives $\frac{7}{\sqrt{6}}$. `SurfaceArea` and `RegionCentroid` can also provide symbolic solutions.

```
spf = squareFrustum[b1, b2, h]; (* square pyramidal frustum *)

Simplify[Volume@spf, {b1>0, b2>0, h>0}]
%/.{b1->2, b2->1, h->height}
```

> ```
> ((b1^2 + b1*b2 + b2^2)*h)/3
> 7/Sqrt[6]
> ```

Use numeric values with `squareFrustum` for direct numeric solutions. `First[sol]` displays the coordinate points.

```
sol = squareFrustum[2, 1, height];
Volume[sol]
SurfaceArea[sol]
(* 7/Sqrt[6] *)
(* 5 + 3*Sqrt[7] *)
```

Graphically, we get:

```
Graphics3D[sol, Boxed->False]
```

[image: square pyramidal frustum]